# What is true bound of penalty area in soccer?

Tags: football

One of the necessary conditions for goal, goal-out or out-of-bounds in football is that ball crosses the pitch boundary line. Since boundary line is 12cm wide, it is my understanding that ball needs to cross **outer** edge of the line with its whole volume. So, here, only first situation is really an out - other two is still inside the pitch.

[image]

My question is - what is appropriate edge of the penalty area? The obvious answer is also the outer edge, because otherwise it would be illegal for goalie to handle the ball that is partially inside goal which would be stupid and inconsistent. But this also means that ball is to be considered **within** penalty area as soon as it "touches" outer edge of boundary line. For example, defender handling the ball in following positions are then:

[image]

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Are you asking about the line/area where a penalty kick is awarded? If yes, it's the players position and the area where the foul is commited that's important, not the position of the ball.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're partly right. The boundary lines belong to the area of which they're boundaries. All of them, not just the touch and goal lines.

This is explained in [Law 1](https://www.theifab.com/laws/latest/the-field-of-play/#field-markings):

> The field of play must be rectangular and marked with continuous lines
> which must not be dangerous; artificial playing surface material may
> be used for the field markings on natural fields if it is not
> dangerous. **These lines belong to the areas of which they are
> boundaries.**

But why partly?

The location of the ball is irrelevant. The position of the foul matters. If the ball is outside right on the edge and the hand on the line this would still be a penalty. The hand (offence) is on the line while the ball is not. Same goes for tackles and other physical fouls.

Comment: Thank you. I've learned something today, accepting your answer.